# would diagonalization work in this scenario?

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

consider a countably infinite list of infinite strings.. such that each string has an ordinal of $ \ \bf ɷ.2 \ $, and the entire list also has an ordinal of $ \ \bf ɷ.2 \ $. Can we use cantor's diaonalization on this list in this manner ?

I think we should be able to do that, and the diagonalized string would also have an ordinal of $ \ \bf ɷ.2 \ $, but can't find any particular such example on internet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can do that. We may regard each string as a function $f : \omega \cdot 2 \to S$, where $|S| \geq 2$ is the set of characters which the strings take on. We may enumerate the set of strings $\{f_\alpha : \alpha < \omega \cdot 2\}$, and define the diagonalisation $g : \omega \cdot 2 \to 2$ by stipulating that $g(\alpha) \neq f_\alpha(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha < \omega \cdot 2$. Then $g \neq f_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.

Comment: so , what can we say about the ordinality of $ \ \bf g \ $, it should also be $ \  \bf ɷ.2 \ $ right ? afterall each element in the diagonal had a particular ordinal, and $ \ \bf g \ $ never altered the ordinality of the diagonal...

Comment: i need this doubt answered before i can accept an answer......

Comment: $g$ is a function of domain $\omega \cdot 2$, so you may see it as an infinite string of order type $\omega \cdot 2$.